# Flutter How to add Switch Border

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make the toggle button in the picture below, but I couldn't add a border. Can you help me with this?
Also, I couldn't understand whether the button in this image is switch or cupertino. I will be glad if you inform me about this.

[image]

My Simple Code;

```
CupertinoSwitch(
              value: true,
              onChanged: (value) {},
              activeColor: CupertinoColors.white,
              thumbColor: CupertinoColors.activeOrange,
            ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create your own custom switch class to be able to achieve what you want.

Create a custom_switch class like below:

```
class CustomSwitch extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool value;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;

  const CustomSwitch({Key? key, required this.value, required this.onChanged})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomSwitchState createState() => _CustomSwitchState();
}

class _CustomSwitchState extends State<CustomSwitch>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController? _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 30));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _animationController!,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            if (_animationController!.isCompleted) {
              _animationController!.reverse();
            } else {
              _animationController!.forward();
            }
            widget.value == false
                ? widget.onChanged(true)
                : widget.onChanged(false);
          },
          child: Container(
            width: 60.0,
            height: 30.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.orange, width: 2),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 2.0, bottom: 2.0, right: 2.0, left: 2.0),
              child: Container(
                alignment:
                widget.value ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Container(
                  width: 25.0,
                  height: 25.0,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.orange),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Then call your custom_switch class as follows:

```
bool _toggle = false;

CustomSwitch(
            value: _toggle,
            onChanged: (bool val){
              setState(() {
                _toggle = val;
              });
            },
          ),
```

Edit the custom_switch class to suit your own need.

Comment: wow! Amazing!! Very very nice work! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 3):

From iOS 14 the default look changed to not having the border.

The conversation can be found [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63407)

So if you are using the Cupertino styling - you should NOT be making this kind of change.

[image]

With usage of `CupertinoSwitch` you can achieve it this way:

```
           Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                color: _value
                    ? CupertinoColors.activeOrange
                    : CupertinoColors.activeOrange,
              ),
              child: CupertinoSwitch(
                value: _value,
                activeColor: CupertinoColors.white,
                trackColor: CupertinoColors.white,
                thumbColor: CupertinoColors.activeOrange,
                onChanged: (v) => setState(() {
                  _value = v;
                }),
              ),
            ),
```

But you asking this kind of question makes me think that you don't want native iOS styling, so consider if you want have more freedom over styling consider moving to `MaterialApp` (even if iOS is your target)

Comment: wow! Amazing!! Very very nice work! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 2):

**This code snippet will work what you want.** *Let me know when you find better solution. Thanks!*

```
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(color: CupertinoColors.activeOrange, width: 2),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                            ),
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width: 51,
                              height: 31,
                              child: CupertinoSwitch(
                                value: true,
                                trackColor: Colors.transparent,
                                onChanged: (value) {},
                                activeColor: Colors.transparent,
                                thumbColor: CupertinoColors.activeOrange,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
```

Comment: wow! Amazing!! Very very nice work! Thank you sir!